# Cors error for all Cargo Collective sites on my laptop

Tags: dns, cors

I keep having a very strange issue with my laptop, where every time I load a cargo collective site, I get the following CORS error.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://type.cargo.site/files/NeueHaasGroteskText-BoldItalic.woff. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

On a different computer in the same wifi network, the site will load fine. This is the case for *all* cargo sites for me, and has been so for over a year! Would appreciate any help resolving.

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Reason: CORS request did not succeed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed)
lists the following possible reasons for this error.
It's up to you to verify if one of the following explains the problem:

- A browser plugin (e.g. an ad blocker or privacy protector) blocking
  the request
- Accessing an https resource that has an invalid certificate
- Accessing an http resource from a page with an https origin
- As of Firefox 68, https pages are not permitted to access
  `http://localhost`, although this may be changed by
  [Bug 1488740](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1488740)
- The server did not return any data.

Comment: hm, I don't think it's any of these -- I've tried w/ multiple browsers on my computer, including Safari, which I don't touch for anything else. I've also tried switching http/https for the sites themselves. And the sites definitely exist and work! I borrow other peoples' computers to look at them...